# eBay API VerifyAddItem returns error on Child Element

Tags: xml, ebay-api

I am calling VerifyAddItem in the sandbox trading api. As a test, I am creating a very simple XML body. Here is the pretty print version:

```
 <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <VerifyAddItemRequest xmnls="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Item>
       <Country>
          US
       <Currency>
          USD
       <Description>
          Antique Table circa 1795
       <PaymentMethods>
          PayPal
       <PrimaryCategory>
          <CategoryID>
             20081
       <ListingDuration>
          Days 30
       <Quantity>
          1
       <Site>
          0
       <StartPrice>
          100.00
```

No error is returned; however, the response message is basically:

Schema XML request error: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.

The XML is valid, so why am I getting this error? The only element with a child element is the PrimaryCategory, which contains a CategoryID element, which is the same as in the sample code for VerifyAddItem: CategoryType string

I have posted this issue with the eBay Dev Forum, but have received no replies.